# New Line for Chatbot

Tags: vb6

`If ChatBot.Caption = ("Bob" & ": " & "Hello! My name is bob. What's your name?") Then
ChatBot.Caption = vbNewLine(Text.Text & ": " & Text.Text)`

This is my code so far. How do you add a new line in this case, I've been trying and searching and couldn't find a thing. With every new line from the textbox, it will add a new line to the ChatBot RichTextBox like: "[username]: blah blah".

I've found out that vbCRLF can also make a new line but honestly have no idea where to place it.

Answer (score 2):

For a RichTextBox the best way is to:

```
'// move cursor to the end of the text
rtb.SelStart = Len(rtb.Text)

'// append the text ending with a new line
rtb.SelText = "Hello" & vbCrLf
```

A lesser alternative is:

```
rtb.Text = rtb.Text & vbCrLf & "New Line 1" & vbCrLf & "New Line 2" & vbCrLf & "New Line 3 ..."
```